# How can we create same instance of var in swift language

Tags: swift

```
 var one = "one"
 var two = "two"
 two = one
 one = "three"
 println(one)
 println(two)
```

it outputs:
three
one

Is there any method to make same instance of string?

Comment: Strings are structs thus this is expected behavior

Comment: so we can't make same instance as we do in objective-C

Comment: Vars aren't pointers? Or are they? I didn't get into Swift too much yet.

Comment: The equivalent Objective-C code for your example would behave exactly the same way, since you're reassigning the `one` pointer, not changing the object.

Comment: similar to C#, a variable can be reference type (class) or value type (struct/enum). value type are always copied. and String is value type. (but your example is totally unrelated to these)

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap the String var inside a class object, then assign the objects and print the object String contents, you will get your desired assign-by-reference behavior.  That's because var objects are referenced by pointers, but var Strings by struct copies.

Comment: Even if strings were reference types, the code as written would produce the exact same result.